# Combine results of different tables to create an alphabetic list

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I did my homework but couldn't find any answer on the question below...

I'd like to create an "**alphabetic index**" made of the results of two (or more) tables of my MySQL-database.

**TABLE 1** is "search_words", with fields to use: id - **search_word**

**TABLE 2** is "categories", with fields to use: id - **category_name**

So what I need is an alphabetically sorted list with the results of these two tables, the **mixed output** of the fields "search_word" AND "category_name", but sorted alphabetically. As they have no relationship, these tables are not joinable, I guess.

Is there a possibility or is the answer simply "No, there isn't!"?

Thanks in advance for any reply, help or redirect to previously posted topics cocerning this issue.

Comment: A table, in relational theory, has no notion of order, so fundamentally you cannot do it. The question then becomes, do you wish to create a condensed view of these two tables (which is possible, but you will have to "order by" yourself), or do you just wish to have a query returning the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,search_word AS word FROM search_words
UNION
SELECT id,category_name AS word FROM categories
ORDER BY word
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, test 
FROM (SELECT id,search_word AS test
      FROM search_words 
      UNION 
      SELECT id,category_name AS test 
      FROM categories 
     ) AS a 
ORDER BY test;`
```

Answer (score 0):

With a WHERE

`SELECT email AS emailList
                         FROM tableA 
                        WHERE tableA.email LIKE "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"
                        UNION
                       SELECT email AS emailList
                         FROM tableB
                        WHERE tableB.email LIKE "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%"`